# range grouping list of strings and numbers

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, grouping

I have a list looks like that

`String[] lst = {BB,2,1,3,AA,DD,A3,A1,EE,A2,4);`

I need to group & range that list, but having trouble with that,
need to find something like this as a result

> result: (1-4),(A1-A3),(AA-BB),(DD-EE)

The code I came up with is this

```
Map<Character, List<String>> collect;

collect = Arrays.stream(str).
flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]"))).
filter(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty()).
sorted().
collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.charAt(0)));
```

but it groups by the first letter, which means AA grouped with A1-A3, and so on.
its not that trivial grouping, and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This is a relatively complex problem, consider looking into general purpose parsers, such as https://www.antlr.org/ . This is a powerful tool that allows you to specify a "grammar", which defined types of tokens. If this is not what you want, you can create an Enum representing groups, and hard code a function that assigns a type to an input string.

Comment: What are the possible inputs and what is the definition for a contiguous group? You imply that `AA` and `BB` are contiguous and that `DD` and `EE` are contiguous, but what about something like `AB`, where would that fall? If it could fall between `AA` and `BB` then those two were not contiguous to begin with.

Comment: Xtratic, such a combination is not valid for my range grouping

Comment: So your possible element types are, a number (eg. `1, 5, 9`), double letters (eg. `AA, BB, ZZ`), or a letter and number (eg. `A1, A2, Z9`), is this correct? And only elements of the same type can be in a range together, you can't go from `A9 - AA`? Inputs `{1, 3, 4, 5,  AA, BB, FF, ZZ, A1, A2, A5, B1, B2}` will result in `{(1), (3 - 5), (AA - BB), (FF), (ZZ), (A1 - A2), (A5), (B1 - B2)}`?

Comment: @xtratic that is correct

Answer (score 0):

As another user has mentioned in the comments, rolling your own solution is not straightforward. To solve this particular problem you can do something like

```
    String[] str = {"BB","2","1","3","AA","DD","A3","A1","EE","A2","4"};
    Map<String, List<String>> collect;

    collect = Arrays.stream(str)
            .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")))
            .filter(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty())
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> {
                final StringBuilder groupKey = new StringBuilder();
                char first = s.charAt(0);
                if (Character.isAlphabetic(first)) {
                    if (first >= 'D') {
                        groupKey.append("ALPHA-HIGH");
                    } else {
                        groupKey.append("ALPHA-LOW");
                    }
                } else {
                    groupKey.append("NON-ALPHA");
                }
                if (s.length() == 2) {
                    char second = s.charAt(1);
                    if (Character.isAlphabetic(second)) {
                        if (first >= 'D') {
                            groupKey.append("_ALPHA-HIGH");
                        } else {
                            groupKey.append("_ALPHA-LOW");
                        }
                    } else {
                        groupKey.append("_NON-ALPHA");
                    }
                }
                return groupKey.toString();
            }));
```

Which will give you the output you're looking for. Note that a key (String) is used instead of a single character.

What's going on here? You've got lots of different possible groups which I see as two macro-groups: alphabetic and non. The non alphabetic stuff *in your case* is numeric. The strings of length 2 can have the second character as alpha or as numeric. The alpha characters are considered "high" if they're `D` or greater.

Output

four groups:

```
NON-ALPHA: {1, 2, 3, 4}
ALPHA-LOW_NON-ALPHA: {A1, A2, A3}
ALPHA-HIGH_ALPHA-HIGH: {DD, EE}
ALPHA-LOW_ALPHA-LOW: {AA, BB}
```

Answer (score 0):

To build such continious groups, you first need to define a function which taking two items identify if they follow each other, i.e. stand in continious order. E.g. "1" is followed by "2", but not by "3" nor "A"; "AA" is followed by "BB" in your example. Having such a function, you iterate over sorted list and comparing neghboring items decide whether to open a group, close it, or print an item standalone.

I'd call such function `follows(String a, String b)`. Then the algotithm to build groups is as simple as:

```
static String printGroups(String[] items) {
  Arrays.sort(items);      // strictly saying, sorting order must be consistent with `follows`
  boolean open = false;    // a group is open currently
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    if (!open && i > 0) {
      result.append(',');
    }
    if (i < items.length - 1 && follows(items[i], items[i + 1])) {
      if (!open) {
        // open a group
        result.append('(').append(items[i]).append('-');
        open = true;
      }
    } else if (open) {
      // close the group
      result.append(items[i]).append(')');
      open = false;
    } else {
      // print a standalone item
      result.append(items[i]);
    }
  }
  return result.toString();
}
```

The `follows` function, adjusted to your example (looks awful, you may make it more clear/readable using java streams or `StringUtils` or whatever) --

```
static boolean follows(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() != b.length() && a.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    // AAA -> BBB
    if (allSame(a) && allSame(b) && (b.charAt(0) - a.charAt(0) == 1)) {
        return true;
    }
    // ABC1 -> ABC2
    // finding common prefix
    int p = 0;
    while (p < a.length() && a.charAt(p) == b.charAt(p)) {
        ++p;
    }
    return (p == a.length() - 1) && (b.charAt(p) - a.charAt(p) == 1);
}

static boolean allSame(String chars) {
    char s = chars.charAt(0);
    return chars.chars().allMatch(c -> s == c);
}
```

After that, you just split a text to items and feed:

```
printGroups("BB,2,1,3,AA,DD,A3,A1,EE,A2,4".split(","));  // (1-4),(A1-A3),(AA-BB),(DD-EE)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've tried to challenge your code with the next list<br> String[] lst =  = {"C1","AA","B1","CC","A2","C2","1","BB","5","4","2","A1","3","A3"};

Comment: it missed a few items, because of the sorting, so I've came up with a different sorting<br>one that Sort Such combination like here: A1,A2..B1,B2.. AA,BB.. and not as the default sorter do A1,A2..AA,B1,B2.. BB..

Comment: I've marked in the code: sorting order must be consistent with `follows` function. That means, you must sort with a comparator which employs a special order [AA, BB, B1], not natural (lexicographical) order [AA, B1, BB]

Comment: the new sorter fixed the missing range issue, but skip the closing of the last range group.    let's say the last group should be (1-3), then the Result:  [(A1-A3),(B1-B2),(AA,CC),(1-] So I just added the last character from the "items" list, if the last character from the "ranges" list was '-'. and that fixed that issue.   Thank you for your help, that solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.

This will work for any given `AdjacentAwareComparator` so long as it's implemented correctly for its value space. The below `comparator` is for the value space you defined.

You can easily adapt `getRanges` to accept a `List` rather than array or to only store the first and last of a range if you don't want all the elements:

```
import static java.lang.Character.isDigit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    /**
     * Marker interface.
     * 
     * Implementors MUST adhere to all contracts of Comparator, and MUST return -1 or 1 if and only if
     * the compared values are adjacent to one another within the set of all possible values.
     */
    @FunctionalInterface public interface AdjacentAwareComparator<T> extends Comparator<T> {};

    /**
     * Assumes the input is valid in the defined value space.
     * 
     * Sort order: Digit (natural), Alpha+Digit (by alpha, then by digit), Alpha+Alpha (natural)
     */
    private static AdjacentAwareComparator<String> comparator = (x, y) -> {
        // uses 2 and -2 to compare values as non-adjacent
        if (x == null) return (y == null) ? 0 : -2;
        if (y == null) return 2;
        // both are not null...

        if (x.isEmpty()) return y.isEmpty() ? 0 : -2;
        if (y.isEmpty()) return 2;
        // both are at least length 1...

        char x1 = x.charAt(0), y1 = y.charAt(0);
        if (isDigit(x1)) return isDigit(y1) ? (x1 - y1) : -2;
        if (isDigit(y1)) return 2;
        // both start with letters...

        int d1 = x1 - y1; // delta between first chars
        char x2 = x.charAt(1), y2 = y.charAt(1);
        if (isDigit(x2)) return isDigit(y2) ? ((d1 == 0) ? (x2 - y2) : (d1 * 2)) : -2;
        if (isDigit(y2)) return 2;

        // the strings are double letters (eg. 'AA' and 'BB')
        return d1;
    };

    public static <T> List<List<T>> getRanges(T[] arr, AdjacentAwareComparator<T> comp) {
        if (arr.length == 0) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        List<List<T>> ranges = new ArrayList<>();
        List<T> range = new ArrayList<>();

        // sort using the custom Comparator
        Arrays.sort(arr, comp);
        T prev = arr[0];
        range.add(prev);

        // iterate through the sorted array
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            T curr = arr[i];
            int d = comp.compare(prev, curr);
            if (d < -1 || 1 < d) {
                // prev and curr are not adjacent nor equal, so start a new range
                ranges.add(range);
                range = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            range.add(curr);
            prev = curr;
        }
        ranges.add(range);
        return ranges;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"4","1","BB","ZZ","A1","5","A5","FF","3","B2","A2","B1","AA"};
        for (List<String> range : getRanges(arr, comparator)) {
            System.out.println("{" + String.join(", ", range) + "}");
        }
        // prints:
        //   {1}
        //   {3, 4, 5}
        //   {A1, A2}
        //   {A5}
        //   {B1, B2}
        //   {AA, BB}
        //   {FF}
        //   {ZZ}
    }
}
```